# Is there any way to avoid activex in javascript for reading Documents and constructing xmls?

Tags: javascript, jscript, activexobject, jscript.net

In need of desperate guidance.

1. Is there any way to avoid activex in javascript for reading Documents and constructing xmls?
2. Actual there is an problem with the client, he doesnt like the IE security settings like "Access data source across domains" under Miscellaneous and "Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins".

And It should support IE 7,8 and above.If possible that should work in cross browser also.

Currently in Javascript, we are using the below codes:

`var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");` -->for xml construction.

`var stm = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");` --> for reading the doc and docx file from client temporary path.

What is needed:

1. We need to find an alternate in order to avoid using the `ActiveXobject`.

OR

1. We need to automate the Internet Security Settings in client machine.And this is should be the one time work.

Could some one help me in this please?

Thanks
Nanda